# How can i write test for huey scheduled task?

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-huey

Im writing test for schedule task, but the task_id return always None

```
update_task_id = update_delivery_minutes_change.schedule(
    args=(instance.id,),
    delay=(60 * 30)
)
update_task_id.task.task_id -> None
```

How can i mock or emulate huey for create a test case?

Comment: Hi, Can you not use the flag `debug=True` ? https://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django.html#debug-and-synchronous-execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with immediate mode:

```
huey.immediate = True
```

see: [Immediate mode](https://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html#immediate-mode)